# xrdp keyboard settings not working in a terminal

Tags: xrdp

I'm working with ubuntu 12.04, in french, with belgian keyboard.

I'm also using xrdp 0.5.0-2.

I did

```
setxkbmap -layout be
sudo cp km-0409.ini km-0409.ini.bak    
sudo xrdp-genkeymap km-0409.ini
```

Using remote desktop connection under windows 7, the login screen seems ok.  The keyboard is belgian.  Alt-gr keys are working.

But in a terminal :

- alt-gr keys are not working
- arrows keys are not working
- insert/home/pg up/pg donw/end/delete are not working
- on the numeric keypad, / and enter are not working.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this web page. This page describes your problem and possibly the workaround might work for you

http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=3858

This might solve your issue

See ya

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Try and answer the question in your own words.

Comment: Hello, yes I know it's resoving the problem.  Very good job from Griffon.